# Simple WPF DataBinding of a ListBox to an ObservableCollection of strings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, .net-4.0

Okay, I just don't get it. Please tell me why I get no items in my ListBox (should be the two strings "empty" and "stuff" right now ):

XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <Windows:SettingsWindowModel x:Name="model"/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Name="listBoxActivities" SelectionChanged="ListBoxActivitiesSelectionChanged"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IgnoredActivities}"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinHeight="40" MinWidth="200"
 Padding="5,100,5,0" Height="100" Margin="0,207,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}" />
```

In SettingsWindowModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<String> _ignoredActivities;
    public ObservableCollection<String> IgnoredActivities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ignoredActivities == null)
            {
                // empty
                _ignoredActivities = new ObservableCollection<String>() { "empty","stuff" };
            }
            return _ignoredActivities;
        }
    }
```

Anything more you need to know? What did I forget?

EDIT:
Maybe I should add that VisualStudio + ReSharper also show no underlines and compile errors. Not even warnings.

Comment: model must be a property, ie, have a {get; set;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, the data was there all the time. The problem was in the visual details. The padding also got applied to a sub-container of the ListBox (or the items), **therefore the items were not sitting at the top of the list. As I've but a height on the ListBox, the items always were below the visible height of the ListBox**. Stange thing to debug. Thanks for your answers anyways!

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need to set the DataTemplate

2) Are you sure the DataContext of the view (aaaaa.xaml.cs) is the ViewModel (bbbbb.cs, contains IgnoredActivities)?

It should be like this:

aaaaa.xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IgnoredActivities}" />
```

aaaaa.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class aaaaa : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new bbbbb();
    }
}
```

bbbbb.cs :

```
    public class bbbbb : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bbbbb()
        {
            IgnoredActivities.Add("empty");
            IgnoredActivities.Add("stuff");
        }

        private ObservableCollection<String> _ignoredActivities;
        public ObservableCollection<String> IgnoredActivities
        {
            get
            {
                if (_ignoredActivities == null)
                {
                    // empty
                    _ignoredActivities = new ObservableCollection<String>() { "empty","stuff" };
                }
                return _ignoredActivities;
            }
        }

            #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void RaisePropertyChanged(string _Prop)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_Prop));
            }

            #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not in the code you posted. You don't show where you set the DataContext

Answer (score 0):

With this statement you are binding to a property "IgnoredActivities" in a control named "model" of your Window.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=model, Path=IgnoredActivities}"
```

When working with ViewModels, set them as the DataContext of your control:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IgnoredActivities}">
    <ListBox.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </ListBox.DataContext>        
</ListBox>
```

A binding with no source specified ("{Binding PathToMyPropert}") defaults to the control's DataContext, which is inherited from parent controls. So in your case, you could set your ViewModel to your Window's DataContext so it will be available to all its children:

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>        

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IgnoredActivities}"/>    
</Window>
```

Comment: As you can see in the code I provided, the Windows' DataContext is set to the SettingsWindowModel. As you can see in the code I provided, the IgnoredActivities property is there and returns data.

Comment: Sorry, it got swallowed by the text edit on this site. My apologies.

Comment: No need for x:Name in your ViewModel instance, it is already cascaded to all the Window's children. And I believe that the target for a x:Name, in a sense that it will be useful for your app, must be a FrameworkElement. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx

Comment: And this one http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f677b026-0719-47d7-a0b7-a0874df2ba17

Comment: Have you tried to make your bindings work first and then apply templates, hook events, etc, with your list box? The bindings work if you start from a simpler xaml like the second example in my answer? The listbox should show your strings out of the box.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I debugged a lot and am sure that the binding looks correct, the data is returned by the property and it really SHOULD be shown in the GUI. I hoped it would be a stupid mistake, and someone here would see it. But bad luck. I'll try setting up a fresh empty project first, somehow maybe my styles screw me up. Will report back when I know more.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that `ElementName` binding property. It's used to bind to WPF controls. Simply set `ItemsSource={Binding IgnoredActivities}`

Answer (score 0):

Try it as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IgnoredActivities}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ListBox />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding}"  />
       </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: ItemsControl doesn't work with ListBoxes (only with Panels/PanelLayouts), throws an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try also setting the DataContext for the control in code behind.

```
Xaml       - <ListBox Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding IgnoredActivities}"/>    
CodeBehind - myListBox.DataContext=this;
```